# Unable to chain the Deferred object Jquery with promise with Jquery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am working on a framework that add chain a validation logic at run time. That logic can the sync / async / ajax call / timeout. Following is the javascript code

```
var Module = {
    Igniter: function (sender) {
        var getIgniter = function (model) {
            let deferred = $.Deferred();
            model.vCount = 0;
            deferred.resolve({ model: model });
            return deferred.promise();
        };
        return getIgniter(sender);
    },
    Required: function (sender) {
        let deferred = $.Deferred();
        sender.model.vCount++;
        console.log("Msg:: Required ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
        deferred.resolve({ model: sender.model });
        return deferred.promise();
    },
    Regex: function (sender) {
        let deferred = $.Deferred();
        //setTimeout(function () {
            sender.model.vCount++;
            console.log("Msg:: Regex ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
            deferred.resolve({ model: sender.model });
        //}, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    },
    Date: function (sender) {
        let deferred = $.Deferred();
        //setTimeout(function () {
            sender.model.vCount++;
            if (sender.model.id != 1)
                deferred.resolve({ model: sender.model });
            console.log("Msg:: Date ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
        //}, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    },
    Number: function (sender) {
        //console.log("Number Called ::", sender);
        let deferred = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            sender.model.vCount++;
            deferred.resolve({ model: sender.model });
            console.log("Msg:: Number ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
            return deferred.promise();
        }, 2000);
        return deferred;
    },
};
```

Calling the code as

```
var model = { id:1 , name: 'Mayank', vCount: 0 };
function CheckValid()
{
    Module.Igniter(model)
        .then(Module.Number)
        .then(Module.Regex)
        .then(Module.Number)
        .then(Module.Date)
        .then(Module.Number)
        .then(Module.Required)
        .then(Module.Number)
        .then(Module.Required);
}
```

I am unable to achieve functional chaining in the above code.

What i am doing wrong.

Edit: As Per comments updating the Module

```
var Module = {
    Igniter: function (sender) {
        var getIgniter = function (model) {
            let deferred = $.Deferred();
            model.vCount = 0;
            deferred.resolve({ model: model });
            return deferred.promise();
        };
        return getIgniter(sender);
    },
    Required: function (sender) {
        let deferred = $.Deferred();
        sender.model.vCount++;
        console.log("Msg:: Required ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
        deferred.resolve({ model: sender.model });
        return deferred.promise();
    },
    Regex: function (sender) {
        let deferred = $.Deferred();
        //setTimeout(function () {
            sender.model.vCount++;
            console.log("Msg:: Regex ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
            deferred.resolve({ model: sender.model });
        //}, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    },
    Date: function (sender) {
        let deferred = $.Deferred();
        //setTimeout(function () {
            sender.model.vCount++;
            deferred.resolve({ model: sender.model });
            console.log("Msg:: Date ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
        //}, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    },
    Number: function (sender) {
        //console.log("Number Called ::", sender);
        let deferred = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            sender.model.vCount++;
            deferred.resolve({ model: sender.model });
            console.log("Msg:: Number ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
        }, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    },
};
```

But Still the order of method resolve is not in proper order.

**Edit :**

As suggested by @charlietfl i have moved the console.log before defer resolve. Final solution is given below.

```
var Module = {
    Igniter: function (sender) {
        var getIgniter = function (model) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            model.vCount = 0;
            deferred.resolve({ model: model });
            return deferred.promise();
        };
        return getIgniter(sender);
    },
    Required: function (sender) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        sender.model.vCount++;
        console.log("Msg:: Required ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
        deferred.resolve(sender);
        return deferred.promise();
    },
    Regex: function (sender) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        //setTimeout(function () {
            sender.model.vCount++;
            console.log("Msg:: Regex ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
            deferred.resolve(sender);
        //}, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    },
    Date: function (sender) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        //setTimeout(function () {
            sender.model.vCount++;
            deferred.resolve(sender);
            console.log("Msg:: Date ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
        //}, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    },
    Number: function (sender) {
        //console.log("Number Called ::", sender);
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            sender.model.vCount++;
            console.log("Msg:: Number ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
            deferred.resolve(sender);
        }, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    },
    ChartValid: function (sender) {
        //console.log("Number Called ::", sender);
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $.get("Home/GetData", { id: sender.model.id }, function (data) {
            sender.model.vCount++;
            console.log("Msg:: ChartValid ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
            deferred.resolve(sender);
        });

        //setTimeout(function () {
        //  sender.model.vCount++;
        //  console.log("Msg:: Number ::", sender, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
        //  deferred.resolve(sender);
        //}, 2000);
        return deferred.promise();
    },
};

var model = { id:1 , name: 'Mayank', vCount: 0 };
function CheckValid()
{
    Module.Igniter(model)
        .then(Module.Regex)
        .then(Module.Number)
        .then(Module.Regex)
        .then(Module.ChartValid)
        .then(Module.Date)
        .then(Module.Number)
        .then(Module.Required)
        .then(Module.Number)
        .then(Module.Required);
}
```

Comment: In your example Module.Date never resolve

Comment: Also can't return inside `setTimeout()` in Number. Nowhere to return to

Comment: I have updated the code. @Vanojx1

Comment: I have updated the code. @charlietfl

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any order problem in demo in my answer

Comment: @charlietfl i tried fiddling your solution. https://jsfiddle.net/aarat3Ld/

Comment: OK...`catch()` only available in jQuery version 3. Have to use `fail()` otherwise https://jsfiddle.net/aarat3Ld/1/. The Promises spec uses catch() and jQuery was not really compliant to that spec is why

Comment: @charlietfl The order is not proper. `Module.Number` is resolving after `Module.Regex`, You can see the order in fiddle console.

Comment: strange... if upgrade to jQuery 3 it logs slightly different...

Comment: In `Number` move console.log() before resolve and order is right in console with version 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue is you only resolve in Date if id is not 1 .... but don't have an else to either reject or resolve with something else.

Also don't see why you keep creating a new object in each resolve(). You can pass the same object `sender` to each `then()`

I added a `reject()` in Date below and run 2 models through. Also added extra `then()` and `catch()` to the chain to log valid or invalid

```js
var model = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Mayank',
  vCount: 0
};
var model2 = {
  id: 2,
  name: 'AnotherName',
  vCount: 0
};

function CheckValid(model) {
  return Module.Igniter(model)
    .then(Module.Number)
    .then(Module.Regex)
    .then(Module.Number)
    .then(Module.Date)
    .then(Module.Number)
    .then(Module.Required)
    .then(Module.Number)
    .then(Module.Required)
    .then(function(sender) {
      console.log('valid');
      console.log(sender)
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('error', err)
    });
}




var Module = {
  Igniter: function(sender) {
    var getIgniter = function(model) {
      let deferred = $.Deferred();
      model.vCount = 0;
      deferred.resolve({
        model: model
      });
      return deferred.promise();
    };
    return getIgniter(sender);
  },
  Required: function(sender) {
    let deferred = $.Deferred();
    sender.model.vCount++;
    console.log("Msg:: Required ::", sender.model.id, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
    deferred.resolve(sender);
    return deferred.promise();
  },
  Regex: function(sender) {
    let deferred = $.Deferred();
    //setTimeout(function () {
    sender.model.vCount++;
    console.log("Msg:: Regex ::", sender.model.id, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
    deferred.resolve(sender);
    //}, 2000);
    return deferred.promise();
  },
  Date: function(sender) {
    let deferred = $.Deferred();
    //setTimeout(function () {
    sender.model.vCount++;
    if (sender.model.id != 1) {
      deferred.resolve(sender);
    } else {
      deferred.reject('Module.Date :: Bad id')
    }

    console.log("Msg:: Date ::", sender.model.id, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
    //}, 2000);
    return deferred.promise();
  },
  Number: function(sender) {
    //console.log("Number Called ::", sender);
    let deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
      sender.model.vCount++;
      deferred.resolve(sender);
      console.log("Msg:: Number ::", sender.model.id, " :: ", sender.model.vCount);
      //return deferred.promise();
    }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise();
  },
};

CheckValid(model).then(function(){
  CheckValid(model2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```